# Fix botttom navigation bar keep expanding when its fragment contain Coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have bottom navigation bar activity with a fragment on top of it.
1 out of 3 menus that I have a fragment that uses Coordinator layout as its parent with App bar layout and collapsing toolbar. another menu works fine with Relative layout parent, but the fragment that has Coordinator layout doesn't work pretty well and make the bottom navigation bar expand its height by itself. Here I'm providing my Code and some screenshots. Thankyou

Here is the code of my fragment layout

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="#FFF"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nama_user"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/nama_sample"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lokasi_user"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/lokasi_sample"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/nama_user"
                    android:layout_below="@id/nama_user"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/foodie_user"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_location_on_black_24dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textStyle=""/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/foodie_user"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/foodie_sample"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@id/nama_user"
                    android:layout_below="@id/lokasi_user"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_foodie"
                    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/color_yellow"/>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/lokasi_user"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/foodie_user"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/nama_user"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/review_count_user"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="46"
                        android:textSize="25dp"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Reviews"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/image_user"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_person_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@color/color_grey"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/color_red" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the code of my Activity with a bottom navigation bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#6DCCD1D8"
        android:layout_above="@id/nav_view"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is its activity java

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        DiscoverFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        SearchFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
        ProfileFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
    FrameLayout fragment;
    final Fragment fragment1 = new DiscoverFragment();
    final Fragment fragment2 = new SearchFragment();
    final Fragment fragment3 = new ProfileFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = fragment1;
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.discover_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;
                case R.id.search_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;
                case R.id.profile_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        fragment = findViewById(R.id.fragment_holder);
        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_holder,fragment1, "1").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

[This is how my error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uc1eT.gif)

[Here is a screenshot of my error when I select profile tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nLJJ.png)

it pooped out when I choose profile bar

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you produce a screenshot of the result @Kevin?

Comment: please try removing this line from your XML "android:fitsSystemWindows="true""

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my app when on its error condition. Hope it's what u need @Alok

Comment: @Ezaldeensahb Oh god thankyou. It works perfectly. it seems like I didn't know the real function of fitSystemWindows. Any explanation? appreciate u bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try removing this line from your XML

```
`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

because it sets the padding of the View to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows.